# How to write to a txt file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have the code that i thought would write to a txt file, but it is not working. the path does exist, but the txt file itself does not, which is why i have the "if" statement. I am unsure where the problem is, because the code runs and compiles with no errors. Any help would be useful. Instructions:

### Create some logging code that does the following.

Create a logging class.
Fields

### fileName

Constructor(string)
Sets the file name to the argument.
Creates the file if it does not exist.

### Opens the file and adds a line of text indicating the date.

Methods
Log method that takes a string message and a log level enum (Debug, Warn, Info, Error)
This method will open the file in append mode and add the message and enum as a new line using the following format:

### LogLevel (formatted as 6 characters) Time (HH:mm:ss.ffff) Message

Main
Create your log object.
Call the log object with a message using the warn enum value.
Call the log object with a message using the debug enum value.
Call the log object with a message using the info enum value.
Call the log object with a message using the error enum value.

Here is the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Logging
{
    public class Log
    {
        public enum Levels { Debug, Warn, Info, Error};

        private string path = @"C:\Users\eliotta1130\Desktop\CSharp\Labs\Logging.txt";

        //public string Path { get; set; }
        //public Levels Levels { get; set; }

        public Log(string path)
        {
            this.path = path;
            if(!File.Exists(path))
            {
                File.Create(path);
            }
            StreamWriter textOut = new StreamWriter( new FileStream(
                                                    path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write));
            textOut.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);

            textOut.Close();
        }
        public void tWrite(Levels levels, string message)
        {
            StreamWriter fs = new StreamWriter( new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write));
            fs.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffff")), message);
            fs.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Here is where I am trying to call the class object.

```
namespace Logging
{
    class Logging
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Log files = new Log("Logging.txt");

            files.tWrite(Log.Levels.Debug , "Fix the problem");
            files.tWrite(Log.Levels.Warn , "Fix the problem");
            files.tWrite(Log.Levels.Info , "Fix the problem");
            files.tWrite(Log.Levels.Error , "Fix the problem");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your `fs.WriteLIne(...)` in tWrite a typo?  The parenthesizes are messed up.

Comment: Which path do you check and say it doesn't write your text? It seems you check the desktop file while you should check the file in your bin\debug folder.

Comment: Since `new Log("Logging.txt");` didn't specify a path, look in the bin\debug folder of your solution for your file.

Comment: Why can't you use Log4net instead of manual logging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the code works properly.

But since you are creating the file using `"Logging.txt"` without path, your file will be created in your `bin\debug` folder and you should see logs there.

Or if you need the desktop path, you can use this code:

```
var fullPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
                            , "Logging.txt")
```

And use fullPath to create the file.

Also to append a line to the file, you can simply use such code:

```
var outPut = string.Format("{0}, {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffff")), message);
System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(path, new string[]{outPut});
```

Comment: Where does the var fullPath variable go? i am unclear as to where to put this and what to replace? in the instructions i need the log object to take a string. @Reza Aghaei

Comment: Pass the `fullPath`  to  constructor of `Log`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use like the following:

```
  File.WriteAllText("your path", "The text to write to the file");
```

Or you can append the text to an existing file by using `AppendAllText()`

```
  File.AppendAllText("your path", "The text to write to the file");
```

where File is under `using System.IO;` Namespace.

So your coding will be like This:

```
    public Log(string path)
    {
        this.path = path;
        if(!File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.Create(path);
        }
    }
    public void tWrite(Levels levels, string message)
    {
       string contentToWrite=string.Format("{0}, {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffff")), message);
       File.AppendAllText(path, contentToWrite);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, if only the assignment was that simple. We were instructed to write to a txt file in the way I have posted, but I somehow misplaced a piece of code or a line of code is off. I will add the instructions to this post to make it clearer. @un-lucky

Answer (score 0):

Also you can write like this

```
   using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\eliotta1130\Desktop\CSharp\Labs\Logging.txt", true))
    {
        file.WriteLine(message);
    }
```

Note that the second argument true means it would append your message on existing texts.